# Перегрузка оператора вывода для класса массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

```
Собственно, создаю класс динамических массивов.
```

Для них задаю функции для добавления элемента или удаления. Хочу перегрузить оператор вывода класса, но в том виде, в котором представлено ниже, происходит дичь: если в массив вставить элемент, то оператор вывода показывает новый массив но со старым количеством объектов, то есть не учитывает изменение размера. То же самое с укороченным массивом, только он одно "мусорное" значение добавляет. Как перегрузить оператор, чтобы он учитывал изменение размера класса?

```
class Mass {
    protected:
        int *p;
        int len;
    public:
        Mass(int N = 0) : p(0), len(0)
        {
            if (N > 0) p = new int[N];
            if (p) len = N;
        }
    void insert(int m, int h)
            {
            int *M = new int[len+1];
            for (int i= 0;i<h;i++)
            {
                M[i] = p[i];
            }
            M[h] = m;
            for (int i = (h + 1); i < (len + 1); i++)
            {
                M[i] = p[i - 1];
            }
            delete[]p;
            p = M;
            }

        void erase(int h)
        {
            int *M = new int[len - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < (h - 1); i++)
            {
                M[i] = p[i];
            }
            for (int i = h; i < (len - 1); i++)
            {
                M[i] = p[i + 1];
            }
            delete[]p;
            p = M;
        }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Mass &c) {

            for (int i=0;i<(c.len);i++)
            {
                os << c.p[i] << endl;
            }
            return os;
        }
```

Comment: Вы просто при работе с массивом не меняете `len` - при вставках и удалениях...

Comment: действительно, в insert помогло, но  в erase все равно одно значение теряется почему-то

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто при работе с массивом не меняете `len` - при вставках и удалениях...

Напишите в `erase`

```
int *M = new int[--len];
```

а в `insert`

```
int *M = new int[++len];
```

В циклах `for` соответственно замените `len-1` и `len+1` на просто `len`.